# Webpack HRM typescript recompile issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm using webpack babel typescript react, everything is working well but I'm experiencing a problem when hot reload in dev mode doesn't recompile ts files,
let's say I have a model like this

```
type Model = {
   prop: string;
}
```

the running project shows me 'Compilled successfully'
but if I need to change this prop to number,

```
type Model = {
   prop: number;
}
```

I will receive

```
[tsl] ERROR in /src/app/modules/home/home.component.tsx(14,57)
TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

This error won't disappear till I fully reload/rebuild the project

Also, I have noticed that it only happens when I split models into separate files, like:

```
src/foo.component.ts
src/foo.model.ts
```

in this case, I'm getting this error till I reload the build, but if I have the model in the same file as the component, it is doesn't give any errors

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ES2015",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "paths": {},
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "@types"]
}
```

So how can I make it recompile the file on type changes without a full-restarting project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin